# Programmatically update Google Spreadsheet with JavaScript?

Tags: api, javascript

Is it possible to update a Google Spreadsheet using JavaScript from a web page?

Scenario:

1) User lands on web page

2) JS script executes, modifying Google Spreadsheet

How can this be done?

Comment: You can use google app scripts which triggers an event and also we ca use javascript https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: Thanks but it needs to be run on our own web page.

Comment: @Crashalot Javascript can only access the current page, so you can't access Google's spreadsheet pages from your own web page.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexW! We're aware of this, which is why we're asking if any APIs or Google libraries exist to allow JavaScript on external web pages to modify a Google Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, though I found it difficult.  See here for all the details: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

If it is a private Google Spreadsheet then you'll need to deal with oAuth 2.0 (Google's authentication).  https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

See here for how to do that with Javascript: 
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Authentication

Comment: any inputs for doing it using C#?