# How to update google spread sheet using the javascript

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have to search, but did not find the javascript code that will update the google spread sheet using the post method from a form.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may get better answers from the *Web App* stack. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=apps+script+update+sheet

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/batchupdate), you can use the `batchUpdate` method which lets you update any of these spreadsheet details. Changes are grouped together in a batch so that if one request fails, none of the other (potentially dependent) changes is written.

For example, to update just the Title of a spreadsheet, this would be the request:

Request:
`POST .../v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate`

Request body:

```
{
  "requests": [{
      "updateSpreadsheetProperties": {
          "properties": {"title": "My New Title"},
          "fields": "title"
        }
    }]
}
```

Examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=update+spreadsheet&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Check these related tickets:

- [Programmatically update Google Spreadsheet with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290380/programmatically-update-google-spreadsheet-with-javascript)
- [Update/Add data to Google Spreadsheet Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303174/update-add-data-to-google-spreadsheet-database)
- [Pushing data to Google spreadsheet through JavaScript running in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887737/pushing-data-to-google-spreadsheet-through-javascript-running-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do all the OAuth consents, the following example works great.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

Make sure the listMajors() works in your code.

than on your form.

```
<form method="post" action="somefile-to-receive-your-data.php" onsubmit="return doSomething();">
```

as for the writing api code.

try:

```
function doSomething() {
  gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
        spreadsheetId: 'YourSpreadSheetID',
        range: 'Sheet1!A4:D5',
        majorDimension: "ROWS",
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
        values: [['="20"&LEFT(E4,6)', "9999", "Name", "03-19-17"],
                 ["9999", "Name", "03-19-17"],'="20"&LEFT(E4,6)']
  }).then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
  });
}
```